# Korrekte Schreibung von Taten statt Worte(n)

Tags: grammatical-number

Ist die Schreibung der genannten Phrase mit oder ohne N-Endung korrekt?

> Taten statt Worte**n**

oder

> Taten statt Worte

(Anmerkung: der Ausdruck wird hierbei isoliert, also nicht als Teil eines Satzes, sondern vielmehr als stichpunktartiger Wahlspruch verwendet.)

Answer (score 6):

Kurze Antwort: Ja, "Taten statt Worte" ist korrekt, denn der Plural von "Tat" ist "Taten" und der Plural von "Wort" ist (in diesem Kontext) "Worte".

Aber es ist durchaus möglich, dass man irgendwo "Taten statt Worten" lesen kann. Das oben erwähnte gilt nämlich nur für Nominativ und Akkusativ. Handelt es sich um Dativ, muss es "Taten statt Worten" lauten, wie beispielsweise in:

> Wir können dies nur mit Taten statt Worten vollbringen.

Answer (score 4):

Die kurze Antwort lautet, dass es

> - Taten statt Worte

heißen muss, sofern Sie es, wie Sie in der Anmerkung geschrieben haben, isoliert verwenden möchten. In dem Fall wird *statt* als Konjunktion gebrauch, und der gesamte Ausdruck steht im Nominativ.

### Hintergrund

Im Folgenden richte ich mich nach dem “*Duden 9. Das Wörterbuch der sprachlichen Zweifelsfälle. 8. Auflage, Eintrag statt.*“

Bei *statt* muss man zunächst zwischen der Verwendung als Präposition und der als Konjunktion unterscheiden.

#### *Statt* als Präposition

Als Präposition zieht *statt* meistens den Genitiv nach sich:

> - Er nahm statt *des Schlüssels* einen Dietrich.
> - Sie kaufte statt *der blauen* die schwarze Hose.

Ist der Genitiv im Plural nicht eindeutig erkennbar (wie etwa bei *Eier* oder *Worte*, was bei beiden Nominativ, Genitiv oder Akkusativ sein könnte), so wird der Dativ verwendet (*Eiern*, *Worten*):

> - Ich nehme statt *Eiern* heute mal Speck.
> - Er ließ statt *Worten* Taten folgen.

#### *Statt* als Konjunktion

Als Konjunktion regiert *statt* selbst keinen Kasus. Der richtet sich dann nach dem Verb oder einer Präposition, was man als [Kongruenz](https://de.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kongruenz_(Grammatik)) bezeichnet. Zum Beispiel regiert *folgen lassen* den Akkusativ:

> - Er lässt *Taten statt Worte* folgen.

Hingegen regiert *erinnern* den Genitiv (wenn es ohne die Präposition *an* gebraucht wird):

> - Man erinnert sich eher *positiver statt negativer Ereignisse*.

Wegen der Präposition *mit* muss in dem folgenden Beispiel der Dativ stehen:

> - Er glänzte mit *Taten statt Worten*.

#### Zusammenfassung

Ob es *Taten statt Worte* oder *Taten statt Worten* heißen muss, hängt vom Kontext ab. Beides sind für sich allein genommen grammatikalisch korrekte Formen. In Ihrem Fall ist die erste Form die richtige.

Answer (score 1):

Das hängt davon ab, ob der Ausdruck im Dativ steht oder nicht:

(Ich habe den Ausdruck "*Taten statt Worte*" durch "*der Durchbruch*" ersetzt, da man dann am Artikel - der, dem oder den - den Fall sehr gut erkennen kann.)

**Nominativ** und **Akkusativ**:

> Das sind endlich Taten statt Wort**e**.
>   Das ist endlich **der** Durchbruch.
>
> Wir wollen Taten statt Wort**e** sehen.
>   Wir wollen **den** Durchbruch sehen.

**Dativ**:

> Er überzeugte mit Taten statt Wort**en**.
>   Er überzeugte mit **dem** Durchbruch.

(Im **Genitiv** können diese drei Worte in exakt dieser Reihenfolge meines Erachtens nicht vorkommen.)

> Der Ausdruck wird hierbei isoliert, also nicht als Teil eines Satzes, sondern vielmehr als stichpunktartiger Wahlspruch verwendet.

Also in etwa so:

> Das Wahlprogramm unserer Partei ist vor allem eines:
>   **Der** Durchbruch!
>
> Das Wahlprogramm unserer Partei will nur eines:
>   **Den** Durchbruch!
>
> Das Wahlprogramm unserer Partei glänzt vor allem mit einem:
>   **Dem** Durchbruch!

Auch in diesem Fall muss man zwischen Nominativ, Dativ und Akkusativ unterscheiden.

Würde man den Ausdruck ohne weiteren Text auf ein Plakat schreiben, gehe ich davon aus, dass es sich um den Nominativ handelt:

> **Der** Durchbruch!

Und somit:

> Taten statt Wort**e**!